# IIS picking other project's web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am having a strange and bizarre issue. When I run a web project(MVC4) the IIS is not picking up the web.config file of that project instead of picking current projects web.config.
Although I am not currently running the other project.

When I saw currently running applications in ISS Express.. it showed

```
http://localhost:2126/
http://localhost:2126/actualproject/
http://localhost:2126/otherproject/
```

going to `**http://localhost:2126/**` takes me to otherproject, `**http://localhost:2126/actualproject/**` gives the issue of web.config file. I remember messing up while creating virtual directory..

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Delete all virtual directories and create new. Thats the simplest and fastest solution.

Comment: I tried finding the sites in applicationHost.config files IIS Express folder but couldn't find.
according to http://forums.iis.net/t/1195314.aspx

Where to spot them?